# VMware Kernel Module Updater Error

Tags: linux, vmware, vmware-workstation, kernel

I am using **Fedora 29** and kernel version **Linux 5.0.16-200.fc29.x86_64**. Before the kernel update, the **VMware Workstation 14.1.7** is working fine but after the update, it is giving the **VMware Kernel Module Updater** message and when trying to update it is giving an error. Also tried

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

from the console.

Following are the errors in the console

```
/tmp/modconfig-NqEL4M/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1502:25: error: ‘totalram_pages’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
    extern unsigned long totalram_pages;

/tmp/modconfig-NqEL4M/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1648:4: error: implicit declaration of function ‘do_gettimeofday’; did you mean ‘do_settimeofday64’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
    do_gettimeofday(&tv);

/tmp/modconfig-NqEL4M/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:3203:40: error: macro "access_ok" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
    if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, p, size)) {
                                        ^
/tmp/modconfig-NqEL4M/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:3203:9: error: ‘access_ok’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, p, size)) {

/tmp/modconfig-NqEL4M/vmnet-only/userif.c:145:52: error: macro "access_ok" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
    if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, (void *)uAddr, size) ||
                                                    ^
/tmp/modconfig-NqEL4M/vmnet-only/userif.c:145:9: error: ‘access_ok’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, (void *)uAddr, size) ||
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Linux kernel "access_ok" macro has discarded first parameter "type", so VMware modules source code requires adaptation.

If you may not update your VMware version to 15.1, I propose to build sources from https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git

Reference: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/609330